# Sequelize Unique constraint + paranoid

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, unique-constraint

I have a table that has a unique constraint on a field + paranoid.
In the example below the brand name is the unique value

```
class Brand extends Model {
        static init(sequelize) {
            return super.init(
                {
                    BrandID: {
                        field: "brand_id",
                        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
                        allowNull: false,
                        primaryKey: true,
                        autoIncrement: true
                    },
                    BrandName: {
                        field: "brand_name",
                        type: DataTypes.STRING(40),
                        allowNull: false,
                        unique: true
                    }
                },
                {
                    sequelize,
                    tableName: "brands",
                    timestamps: true,
                    paranoid: true
                }
            );
        }

        static associate(models) {

        }

    };
```

The problem is that once an entity is deleted, I can't add another entity with the same brand name because of the unique constraint, although it is marked as deleted as expected.

I thought to defining the field as part of the model, that is adding that:

```
                    DeletedAt: {
                        field: "deleted_at",
                        type: DataTypes.DATE,
                        allowNull: false,
                        defaultValue: 0
                    }
```

and having a composite unique constraint for the brand name + deleted_at but it fails.

Sequelize must have a built-in solution for that...
Any idea???

Comment: What exactly fails when you tried `brand name + deleted_at` unique constraint?

Comment: I rethought about it and changing\redefining the deleteAt field manually is a bad idea, because Sequelize rely on the field to be null when fetching objects.

So I tried defining a composite unite constraint like that:
```
uniqueKeys: {
                        name_unique: { fields: ['brand_name', 'deletedAt'] }
                    } 
```
but apparently, a unique constraint with null field does not work, as duplicate records with the same name and empty deletedAt can be inserted.

Comment: And does it work?

Comment: No, as I mentioned multiple lines with the same brand name can be inserted.

Comment: And did you create this unique index in DB?

Comment: Sequelize did: {"message":"Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `brands` (`brand_id` INTEGER(11) NOT NULL auto_increment , `brand_name` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, `brand_logo_path` VARCHAR(100), `date_created` DATETIME NOT NULL, `date_updated` DATETIME NOT NULL, `date_deleted` DATETIME, \UNIQUE `name_unique` (`brand_name`, `date_deleted`), PRIMARY KEY (`brand_id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;","level":"debug"}

Comment: Unfortunately unique indexes allow multiple null values, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-unique

Comment: I understand that...
Is there any built-in solution for that in sequelize when using paranoid mode?

Comment: Sequelize can't check uniqueness because for that it would need all records. It's always a task for a DB itself to run such types of integrity checks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a separate column to solve this, for example:

- column `"ConstraintsSalt" boolean default true`
- unique index (https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/indexes/) or constraint on multiple columns - "BrandName" + "ConstraintsSalt"
- extend the paranoid model with "beforeDestroy" hook (https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/hooks/) and set `ConstraintsSalt = null` to break the uniqueness of deleted (aka hidden) records

Answer (score 1):

You can just create index with where clause if you are using the soft delete.

```
await queryInterface.addIndex('Brands', ['brandName'], {
  unique: true,
  name: 'unique_brandName',
  where: {
    deletedAt: null,
  },
  transaction
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest solution, the one sequelize's paranoid feature was created to handle, is to restore the original record. After you restore, you can update that record to meet your needs.

```
// Example showing the static `restore` method.
await Brand.restore({ where: { BrandName: someBrandYouNeedAgain } })
```

https://sequelize.org/master/manual/paranoid.html#restoring